# $X$ is orthogonal to $X-E[X|Y]$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose you have two zero mean Gaussian vectors $X,Y$. Why is $X-E[X|Y]$ orthogonal to $X$ in the sense that the expectation
$$ E[(X-E[X|Y])X^T]=0$$

Comment: What is a condition expectation for you?

Comment: I'd preferably like to see both the naive and the measure theoretic approach to conditional expectation. But I guess what I'm looking for first and foremost is intuition for why this might be the case.

Comment: $X-E[X|Y]$ is orthogonal to $Y$, not to $X$.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong, my bad

Comment: That is interesting if $X-E[X|Y]$ is not orthogonal to $X$; because the notes I'm working off utilize that to prove $E[(X-E[X|Y])(X-E[X|Y]^T)] = \Sigma_{XX} - \Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}\Sigma_{XY}^T$, where $\Sigma_{XX},\Sigma_{YY}, \Sigma_{XY}$ are covariance matrices.